# how can I use a space in between class name and opening { in scss

Tags: sublimetext2

I am working in SCSS with Sublime Text 2, I need automatically add a space after the classname. How can I do that?

currently

```
.classname{
 color:red;
}
```

I need something like this:

```
.classname {
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a `{` with your mouse. Then press <kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select further appearances of `{`. Now use <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.